# 'Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)' error when adding a point in a Django web-app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I have this Django webapp that allows adding a point via Django's OSMGeoAdmin. The database is Postgresql with Postgis installed. When I add a point and save it, it results to this error

[image]

[image]

**mysite/app/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**mysite/mysite/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'website',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'app',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'djangodb',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**C:\Users\imper\miniconda3\envs\django\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py** `_execute()` method

```
def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
        if params is None:
            # params default might be backend specific.
            return self.cursor.execute(sql)
        else:
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

The app's table in my `djangodb` Postgis database
[image]

Comment: OSMGeoAdmin is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/admin/#osmgeoadmin).

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104607/problem-with-geometry-srid-in-postgis